# Audacity Nyquist plugin location in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, plugins, audacity, dotfiles

In Ubuntu, is there a place in my home folder where I can put Nyquist plugins so that Audacity will see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

```
~/.audacity-files/plug-ins
```

[source 1](http://audacity.238276.n2.nabble.com/Per-user-plugins-directory-on-nix-td257328.html) 
[source 2](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/audacity.1.html)